# В python 2.7 не функционирует функция help(object) и __doc__

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Я могу запустить только `help()` и вызвать `str.__doc__`. На любой другой запрос `help(print) help(string)`, а так же вызов `import os help(os)` и в самом вызваном help(). Нечего не работает пишет или  `"more" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.` или `help> help('return')
no Python documentation found for 'help(return)'.`

Может быть я еще зеленый и не понял как все это работает. Пожалуйста помогите, объясните, все перерыл нечего не нашел(

Comment: Ну попробуйте установить редактор more .

Comment: упомяните вашу операционную систему и точную версию Питона. В каком окружении пытаетесь `help()` запустить? В Windows console,
 gnome-terminal, Linux console? Какая REPL? (python, ptpython, ipython, bpython, IDLE, jupyter notebook etc?)

Comment: @AndrioSkur: `more` это не редактор, это pager (утилита командной строки, которая текст постранично показывает)

Comment: @jfs  ОС Windows 7, консоль Windows PowerShell, версия: `Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`  , REPL SublimeText3(полностью стандартные? без плагинов и IDLE и т.д.)

Comment: Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: Если вы в Windows консоли (с cmd) python.exe запустите, то работает help(help)? Или даже просто наберёте `echo text | more`? Какие результаты для: `subprocess.call("more")` vs. 'subprocess.call("more", shell=True)` vs. `os.system("more")` в вашем окружении?

Comment: @jfs при чем тут `echo text | more`?? Это же вообще наверное php. help(help) работает. для все остального результаты те же: `help> os.system("more")
no Python documentation found for 'os.system(more)'` или  
`>>> os.system("more")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined`

Comment: @Vikentsi: `echo text | more` следует в командную строку вводить (на Windows в консоль с `cmd.exe` запущенной) -- это не php. Назначение запуска команды, чтобы понять доступна ли у вас `more` команда в консоли. `os.system('more')` следует в Python REPL запускать (вы дожны видеть, что-то вроде `>>>`), а не внутри `help>`. Назначение аналогично -- убедиться, что `more`  может быть из shell запущено. `os` это стандартный модуль. `import os`  (если вы этого не знали, то прочтите любую книгу по Питону, чтобы не тратить время на решение ошибок подобных ` NameError: name 'os' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Сначала попробуйте переустановить Python с официального источника https://www.python.org/downloads/

Вы также можете попробовать использовать онлайн интерпретатор на сайте https://www.python.org для help-a, но это уже конечно извращение.

P.S. `echo` - в данном случае системная команда вывода текста в консоль.